# How does Honda ensure the all the pins and holes are lined up when VTEC is activated? Shouldn't they interfere?

Tags: honda, engine-theory, vtec

If the outside rocker arms are actuated by a different cam profile than the middle rocker arm, how could these pins ever line up? Isn't it likely that the initial outside pin forces itself against the side of the middle rocker (and not immediately go into the receiving hole of the middle rocker arm) and cause damage?

How does Honda ensure these holes are all lined up perfectly when they activate the VTEC solenoid?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line on this is, they don't have to line up exactly when VTEC is engaged. The pin which locks the VTEC rocker is pushed against the rocker arm and slides into the hole when it gets to the spot. There's no damage because it's designed not to be damaged. Conversely, when the pin is pulled, it doesn't do it until the pin is no longer under strain. All of this happens very quickly, so there's no problems here going either direction.

Comment: If you are mechanically inclined, here's a video explaining Honda's VTEC technology; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSCuRXnfLuI